# Can a structure tag be used before its scope?

Tags: c, struct

In the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct B b;
struct B{int a;}; 

struct B;

int main()
{
    b.a=3;
    printf("%d\n", b.a);
    return 0;
}
```

The file scope of structure tag `B` starts from its first definition/declaration `struct B{int a;};`. 
How can `struct B b;` refer to `B` before `B`'s scope  without error?

Is `struct B;` a structure type declaration, or a structure type definition? Why does it not conflict with the other definition `struct B{int a;};` in the same file scope?

Comment: Google for "incomplete type"

Comment: To answer second question, `struct B;` is a declaration so does not conflict. Just like how you can declare a function signature unlimited number of times but can only define it once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct B;` is a structure *declaration*. There can be any number of declarations of the same object. For the kinds of objects that have multiple possible declarations, the declarations have to be compatible — for example you can have multiple prototypes for the same function, but they need to use the same argument and return types. For a structure, there's only one way to declare it without defining it, and it just says “there's a structure called `B`”. So it's ok to repeat `struct B;` as many times as you want.

`struct B{int a;};` is a structure *definition*. There can only be one definition of a given object. Certain uses of an object require a prior definition, others only require a prior declaration. For example, you can define a variable whose type is a pointer to an undefined structure:

```
struct S;
struct S *p = NULL;
```

But you can't define a variable whose type is an undefined structure:

```
struct S;
struct S s = {0};
```

The reason for this difference is that a structure that hasn't been defined yet is an *incomplete type* — a type for which the compiler doesn't have a size. This isn't a problem to define a pointer, but it is a problem to define an object of the incomplete type: the compiler wouldn't know how much memory is required.

At this point, you may wonder why `struct B b;` is OK. After all, `struct B` hasn't even been declared, let alone defined.

The first part of why it's ok is that `struct B b;` declares the structure `B` in passing. So by the time `struct B` is needed to do something with `b`, the structure has just been declared.

The second part of why it's ok is that `struct B b;` is not exactly a definition. If it was a definition, then the compiler would need to know how much space to reserve, and an incomplete type would not be ok. This is what would happen if the variable was defined in a function:

```
void f(void) {
    struct B b; // error: storage size of ‘b’ isn’t known
}
```

But when `struct B b;` is at the top level of a file, it's a *tentative definition*. A tentative definition is a declaration; for this, the structure doesn't need to have been defined. When the compiler gets to the end of the file, any tentative definition that hasn't had a proper definition, and for which a definition is needed, becomes a definition. At this point, the structure needs to have been defined. In your example program, `b` has a tentative definition, and that definition becomes a proper definition at the end of the file.

It's ok to not define the structure if the variable is unused, because it's ok to declare a variable with an incomplete type if the variable is not used.

```
struct B b;
// end of file
```

But if the variable is used in a way that requires a complete type, then the structure must have been defined at that point.

```
struct B b;
void f(void) {
    sizeof(b); // error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct B’
}
struct B{int a;}; // too late
```

Comment: A tentative definition is a definition. (But that's just a terminology issue, the message you are conveying is correct)

Comment: Thanks, Gilles. Instead of declaring a type tag, [If we declare an object or function without defining it, what can we do with it and what can't we do with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45736720/3284469)

Answer (score 0):

**Question: How can struct B b; refer to B before B's scope without error?**
Answer: From http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.3.html in section 1471,
"If a type specifier of the form *struct-or-union identifier*
occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and no other declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it declares an incomplete structure or union type, and declares the identifier as the tag of that type."
So, you can use the struct tag as forward declaration before the struct type definition.

**Question: Is struct B; a structure type declaration, or a structure type definition? Why does it not conflict with the other definition struct B{int a;}; in the same file scope?**
Answer: From the same above link in section 1472,
"If a type specifier of the form *struct-or-union identifier* or *enum identifier* occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and a declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it specifies the same type as that other declaration, and does not redeclare the tag."

*struct B;* is a structure type declaration, *struct B{int a;};* is a structure type definition and that's how they do not conflict each other.
You may choose to use the *typedef* to get rid of the confusion and show more visibility into your structure declaration:

```
typedef struct B B;
struct B{
    int a;
}; 
B b;
```