# How are we allowed to use a forward-declared object or function, and how are we not?

Tags: c

If we declare an object or function without defining it, how are we allowed to use it before its declaration and how are we not allowed to use it before its declaration ? (For a similar question using a forwarded declared  structure tag before its definition, basically how we are allowed to use an incomplete type and how not, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45725061/3284469)

Does it matter if the declaration appears in file scope or block scope?

Does it matter if its definition appears in the same or a different translation unit?

For example

```
extern int i;

(what can we do with i here?)
(what can't we do with i here?)
int A = i+3; // error: initializer element is not constant. This is an error not due to forward declaration of int i

int i = 3;


void fun();

(what can we do with fun here?)
(what can't we do with fun here?)

void fun(){};
```

Comment: Please clarify whether the lack of definition is valid globally (linker error) or only in the file we are "looking at"? I.e. do you think of completely building or only compiling? To see the context: If only compiling the answer is "everything", if building completely without definition anywhere, the answer is "nothing".

Comment: @Yunnosch  I am considering all the cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring an object is a promise to provide a definition at some other place. Once you declare a function or an external variable, from that point on you are allowed to do anything that you would be allowed to do to a function or a variable that you have defined.

The scope of the declaration has no effect on *what* you can do, only on the location in code *where* you can do it.

In most cases, code translator requires all external references to be satisfied at the time the code is linked. Otherwise, you get a linking error.

One exception to this rule is using declared object in a `sizeof` expression, which does not require an access to underlying object:

```
extern int undefined;
size_t res = sizeof(undefined);
```

The above will not break a link, because `sizeof` expression does not generate access to its arguments.

Comment: Thank you. Does `sizeof(undefined)` work even if `undefined` is not defined anywhere?

Comment: @Ben If `sizeof` is the only place where an undefined external identifier is used, there would be no linkage errors. C99 standard makes an explicit exception from the rule for this situation (see footnote for section 6.9.5: " if an identifier declared with external linkage is not used in an expression, there need be no external definition for it.")

Comment: @Ben - To put it in another way: The compiler can see that `undefined` is an `int`, and it knows that all `int`s in a program have the same size (and how many bytes that is :-).

Answer (score 0):

[www.cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html) say's:

> When you declare a variable, a function, or even a class all you are
>   doing is saying: there is something with this name, and it has this
>   type. The compiler can then handle most (but not all) uses of that
>   name without needing the full definition of that name. **Declaring a
>   value--without defining it--allows you to write code that the compiler
>   can understand without having to put all of the details.** This is
>   particularly useful if you are working with multiple source files, and
>   you need to use a function in multiple files. You don't want to put
>   the body of the function in multiple files, but you do need to provide
>   a declaration for it.

```
extern int i;
```

Here, an **integer** type variable `i` has been declared (but no definition i.e. no memory allocation for variable `i` so far). And we can do this declaration as many times as needed.

```
void fun();
```

Function `fun()` declare, but not defined. but it does tell the compiler that it can use this function and expect that it will be defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything with the declaration except for inlining it.  For example:

```
void fun();
inline void fun(){}
```

After the declaration you can call the function, unless the definition is marked `inline` in which case it will result in a linker error because the definition does not emit a symbol to link against.  Even if you don't say `inline` explicitly, an optimizing compiler may inline calls to the function if the definition has been seen.

Comment: C does not require that an `inline` function declaration be part of a definition.  It requires only that if such a function has external linkage then a definition must appear in the same translation unit.  Also, it is not invalid for some declarations to declare an external identifier `intern` and others not, but that *does* have semantic significance.

Answer (score 0):

> what can we do with i here

With

```
extern int i;
```

1. `i` can be declared as many times as required in the program.
2. You can have an initializer

   ```
   extern int i = 0;
   ```

> what can't we do with i here?

You can't use `i` without defining it in the program.

```
extern int i;
int main(void)
{
    i = 10;    // Will through an error
    return 0;
}
```

In case of function this keyword only tells that the linkage for the function is `extern`. By default linkage of a function declaration/definition is extern.

Comment: "i can be declared as many times as required in the program". I am asking if the forward-declared `i` can be used (not redeclared) before its definition in the same way as if it were already defined.

Comment: @Ben; See the last example in the answer.

Comment: Note that although you *can* do `extern int i = 0;`, it might elicit a compiler warning.  One ordinarily uses `extern` on a file-scope variable declaration to express that it is not also a definition, but providing an initializer counteracts that.